# Custom json response in sequelize.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I using sequelize for getting json from mysql db. So I have two models `Menu` and `Product` further associations like:

**Menu.js**

```
  classMethods: {
    associate: function(models) {
      Menu.hasMany(models.Product, {foreignKey: 'menu_id'})
    }
  }
```

**Product.js**

```
  classMethods: {
    associate: function(models) {
      Product.belongsTo(models.Menu, {foreignKey: 'menu_id'})
    }
  },
  // IF I ADD BELOW CODE I HAVE ERROR: Possibly unhandled ReferenceError: menu is not defined
  instanceMethods: {
     toJSON: function () {
       var values = this.get();
       if (this.Menu) {
         values.icon = menu.icon;
       }

       return values;
     }
   }
```

and

```
 Product.findAll({
      where: { /* id: */ },
      include: [
          { model: Menu }
      ]
  }).success(function(match) {
    res.json(match);
 });
```

Then I get:

```
{
  "id": 3,
  "menu_id": 1,
  "product_title": "whatever",
  "price": 22,
  "createdAt": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
  "updatedAt": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
  "Menu": {
    "id": 1,
    "menu_title": "whatever",
    "icon": "someurlforicon",
    "createdAt": "2014-12-29T00:00:00.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2014-12-29T00:00:00.000Z"
  }
}
```

**Is possible to just extend products array with icon from menu model ? LIKE:**

```
{
  "id": 3,
  "menu_id": 1,
  "product_title": "whatever",
  "price": 22,
  "icon": "someurlforicon",
  "createdAt": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
  "updatedAt": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could add a custom `toJSON` method to the Product model:

```
instanceMethods: {
  toJSON: function () {
    var values = this.get();

    if (this.Menu) {
      values.icon = this.Menu.icon;
    }

    return values;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Jan Thanks for answer! I trying to add your solution but I have error : `Possibly unhandled ReferenceError: menu is not defined`

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit too quick - of course you have to actually access `this.Menu` after checking if it is defined

Comment: Thank you!!! Even next thing Can I remove menu child array somehow? Just have `icon` inside product array ?

Comment: `delete values.Menu` - This is just a plain javascript object we are working with :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Comment: This is outdated as of V4. You need to do Product.prototype.toJSON = function() {} http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/upgrade-to-v4.html

Answer (score -1):

The product and The menu is a many-to-one associations. So Product.find() can't return the product array. Because the product corresponding to a menu.